# Multiple evolutions for multiple databases in the Play Framework

Tags: playframework

I have two databases that I want to store objects in, each mutually exclusive

object1 for database1
object2 for database2

is there a way to automatically "map" or "instruct" each model on what database to be put into during the evolution process

Answer (score 0):

in order to do that you would create two different db connections

```
db.default.driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3600/db_name1"
db.default.user="username"
db.default.password="password"

db.otherDBName.driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
db.otherDBName.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_name2"
db.otherDBName.user="username"
db.otherDBName.password="password"

//then you let ebean know where to find the models
ebean.default="models.*"
ebean.otherDBName="otherDB.models.*"

//you can refer to the otherDBName with 
Ebean.getServer("otherDBName").save(object);
```